# apache segmentation fault stack trace

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, apache2, coredump

Trying to make sense of a stacktrace and any help is appreciated.

```
b#0  0x00007fe60d50658a in gc_remove_from_buffer (root=0x7fe5fdf7b030) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_gc.h:190
190     /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_gc.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fe60d50658a in gc_remove_from_buffer (root=0x7fe5fdf7b030) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_gc.h:190
#1  gc_remove_zval_from_buffer (zv=zv@entry=0x7fe5fdf7b078) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_gc.c:260
#2  0x00007fe60d4d5018 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x7fe5fdf7b078) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_execute.h:78
#3  _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:424
#4  0x00007fe60d4f43b8 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x7fe617242ac8) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_hash.c:548
#5  0x00007fe60d4e4d6b in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0x7fe5fdf7b078) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#6  0x00007fe60d594610 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#7  i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_execute.h:79
#8  zend_vm_stack_clear_multiple (nested=) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_execute.h:308
#9  zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a96478) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:650
#10 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a96478) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#11 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a96478) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#12 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#13 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#14 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a962e0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#15 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a962e0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#16 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a962e0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#17 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#18 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#19 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a96118) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#20 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a96118) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#21 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a96118) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#22 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#23 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#24 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a95fd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#25 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95fd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#26 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95fd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#27 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#28 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#29 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a95ee8) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#30 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95ee8) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#31 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95ee8) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#32 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#33 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#34 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a95d30) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#35 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95d30) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#36 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95d30) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#37 0x00007fe6025ac18d in nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1056
#38 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#39 0x00007fe60d594b1e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fe616a95bd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:592
#40 0x00007fe60d523020 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95bd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#41 0x00007fe60d4d4cf8 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fe616a95bd0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#42 0x00007fe6025ac402 in nr_php_execute_file () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:889
#43 nr_php_execute_enabled () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:921
#44 0x00007fe6025ac982 in nr_php_execute () at /home/hudson/slave-workspace/workspace/PHP_Release_Agent/label/centos5-64-nrcamp/agent/php_execute.c:1167
#45 0x00007fe60d4e77f0 in zend_execute_scripts (type=-34099080, type@entry=8, retval=0x7fe600000000, retval@entry=0x0, file_count=231379392, file_count@entry=3)
    at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/Zend/zend.c:1341
#46 0x00007fe60d483560 in php_execute_script (primary_file=primary_file@entry=0x7ffc9cbfda60) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/main/main.c:2597
#47 0x00007fe60d5961ca in php_handler (r=) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.6.9+dfsg/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:667
#48 0x00007fe614fab290 in ap_run_handler (r=r@entry=0x7fe6150900a0) at config.c:169
#49 0x00007fe614fab7d9 in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x7fe6150900a0) at config.c:433
#50 0x00007fe614fc1672 in ap_process_async_request (r=0x7fe6150900a0) at http_request.c:317
#51 0x00007fe614fc1810 in ap_process_request (r=0x7fe6150900a0) at http_request.c:363
#52 0x00007fe614fbe112 in ap_process_http_sync_connection (c=0x7fe6150a1290) at http_core.c:190
#53 ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7fe6150a1290) at http_core.c:231
#54 0x00007fe614fb4b00 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7fe6150a1290) at connection.c:41
#55 0x00007fe60deb87ba in child_main (child_num_arg=-34099080) at prefork.c:704
#56 0x00007fe60deb8a01 in make_child (s=0x7fe6151a8de0, slot=65) at prefork.c:800
#57 0x00007fe60deb9667 in perform_idle_server_maintenance (p=) at prefork.c:902
#58 prefork_run (_pconf=0x7fe6151f1f38 , plog=0x7ffc9cbfdecc, s=0x7ffc9cbfded0) at prefork.c:1090
#59 0x00007fe614f90e7e in ap_run_mpm (pconf=0x7fe6151e0028, plog=0x7fe6151ae028, s=0x7fe6151a8de0) at mpm_common.c:94
#60 0x00007fe614f8a3c3 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7ffc9cbfe1b8) at main.c:777
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information it's hard to tell something.
It just says that the problem happens during GC. Google for it. I have found two of similar problems: [1](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67314) and [2](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70007).

Secound bug I've encountered in our project